# Xpath not working when recording with chrome browser

Tags: xpath, selenium-ide, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I'm having a problem. When I try to record actions in google chrome using Katalon Studio, sometimes xpath doesnt work well and I need to write xpath attributes by myself. I just want to know if there is a bug or I'm doing it wrong.

I tried also in IE, but I saw the documentations and now I know that IE doesnt have integration with xpath.

Comment: Could you give an example on how the xpath go wrong?

Comment: Sure, I will try now but usually it says that object couldn't be found.

Comment: You need to double check if the xpath you recorded is static or dynamic to have proper solution

Comment: I've recorded now and same problem -> Unable to click on object 'Object Repository/Google_Test/Page_Google/input__btnK' (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable, but when i changed it with my own xpath it worked

Comment: Could you copy the xpath generated by the tool and your own xpath?

Comment: this is my own absolute XPath - /html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[3]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/center[1]/input[1] and it is generated when recording //input[@name='btnK']

Comment: I also have one more question, but I think it will be already asked on stackoverflow and I will search about it.

Comment: and what is the xpath generated by the tool? if you use F12 (developer tool) from the browser and try the xpath, will it work? I could not know what went wrong with  no HTML and an absolute xpath

Comment: I use ChroPath extension and when i copy its xpath everything works well. When I record with Katalon Studio sometimes it works also well, but sometimes it has problems.

Comment: Sorry, but I still not get exactly what went wrong. You might need to provide the HTML and the xpath generated from the tool that go wrong.

Comment: I record actions on google, simple search actions. Yeah maybe I'm explaining it bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is a bug. It is just the way the recorder works.

I would recommend *always* writing the xpath yourself because the recorder-generated xpath tends to be very fragile and breaks easily.

For tips on using xpath selectors in Katalon, see [here](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/xpath_katalon_studio_tips.html).

And when I say "writing the xpath yourself" I really do mean "yourself". Sure, ChroPath or similar tools can help, but when you know how to select the desired attribute, you are in more control and, as an added benefit, you get to know the DOM of the app under test better. See [here](https://devhints.io/xpath) for a short xpath cheatsheet.

Comment: yeah, now when I actually writing xpath myself, everything works well. I had a few problems learning xpath, but now I think i can handle with xpath. Thanks for your advice