# Python script that export from katalon recorder can't run and display error

Tags: python, selenium, automation, katalon-recorder

I am new in automation. Currently, I am using `katalon` recorder to record my web application, Then I want to export it to python2 (webdriver+unittest) to run in my machine...after I run the test script using python, it shows me some errors that unable to locate the element… But when I run in `katalon` recorder, everything just fine.

May I know what steps did  I miss or what should I install or import in order to run the python test script same with the `katalon` recorder. Is there any library that `katalon` using to run the `testscript`?

Thank you.

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question without any code and any page source.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Please don't use the Katalon Studio tag for questions that are related to Katalon Recorder only. I've edited your question to make it more on point with tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954505/xpath-not-working-when-recording-with-chrome-browser/53985352#53985352), automatically generated element locators tend to be pretty flaky, so the best course of action is to learn to use XPath (or other selector strategies) to pinpoint the element yourself.